# How to tell if a journal was in SCI or SCIE at a particular date

Tags: indexing

My institution cares a lot if an article was published on a SCI/SCIE indexed journal. I need to find a way to determine, for instance, American Journal of Surgery was indexed in SCI/SCIE on August 2009 (I need to find such information for dozens of cases). How would you advise I go about this?

Web of science tells me if the journal is indexed in SCI/SCIE now, but I need to find out if it was indexed at a particular date.